# Connecting to Pgmaker Db in to Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to Connect to Pgmaker Db to Superset. However, my password is updating dynamically.
Is there any way to connect to pgmaker db using REST connection to Superset?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a database connection in Apache Superset via the REST API. I am not familiar with Pgmaker, but I assume it is about PostgreSQL.

With the [Superset REST API](https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/) you can use the `/api/v1/database` endpoint.

Here's an example to create a PostgreSQL database in Apache Superset via REST API:

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/v1/database/ \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'X-CSRFToken: token' \
  --data '{
  "database_name": "PostgreSQL Example",
  "engine": "postgres",
  "expose_in_sqllab": true,
  "sqlalchemy_uri": "postgresql://postgres:123456@172.17.0.1:5432/postgres"
  }'
```